# How to make eclipse formatter keep while statement on same line?

Tags: java, eclipse, formatter

I want the eclipse formatter to keep

```
while(condition) doSomething();
```

formatted as-is, rather than changing it to

```
while(condition)
    doSomething();
```

I can't seem to find an option for it to do this.  Is this possible with the eclipse formatter?

Comment: @Berger he probably knows that...@g.rocket I think this is not possible... afaik only possible for `if`s...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of [this commit in July 2018](https://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.core.git/commit/?id=2afe46fe08b73fc054c0d0e96e3f631da8bb4ac5), this is now possible.

The eclipse formatter now contains the options "Keep simple 'for' loop body on same line," "Keep simple 'while' loop body on same line, and "Keep simple 'do while' loop body on same line," which do exactly what I originally asked for.

In settings -> Java -> formatter, if you click "Edit", you can find them under New Lines -> In control statements -> Simple loops

[image: Eclipse formatter preferences]

Comment: Personally I no longer thing this sort of formatting is a good idea, but it is an option now, so I figured I'd post this here to let people know.

Answer (score 3):

That's true - that setting is not (yet) available (see [this bug report/feature request](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=104910))

I'd recommend anyway to format to

```
while(condition) {
    doSomething();
}
```

Even if this adds length to your code, I still believe it easiest to read and modify.

Comment: +1 Readability and maintainability should never suffer just because of lazyness. Curly braces not only help on determining when and where a block opens and closes but also add explicit structure to code.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such a configuration value. You can use

```
//@formatter:off
while(true) doStuff();
//@formatter:on
```

To let eclipse not format the code. But you need to configure eclipse's formatter for it.

Or you get eclipse's source and implement your very own formatter.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is not possible, judging by [this recently-updated bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=104910).

If you'd asked, I'd add on a personal level, 'which is great because this kind of formatting is horrific for many reasons', but you didn't ask, so I'll stay quiet on the subject :P